# Convert case of a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where the case of a particular column is inconsistent and I want to make it consistent:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"vals":["alpha","Beta","GAMMA"]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    vals
0  alpha
1   Beta
2  GAMMA
```

Is there is an easy, pythonic way to replace each value with the `str.upper()` of the string `str` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
df['vals'] = map(lambda x: x.upper(), df['vals'])
```

Or even:

```
df['vals'] = df['vals'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

---

Ps.: in recent versions you may also:

```
df['vals'] = df['vals'].str.upper()
```

Comment: Thanks. I searched online for quite some time and couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Version 0.18.0 is not recent enough; it gives: 

```df['Position'] = df['Position'].str.capitalize()
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':```

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
df['vals'] = df['vals'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the changes inplace directly on your dataframe:

> `df["vals"].apply(lambda x: x.upper())`

Here `.upper()` will work whether your elements are of type `str` or `unicode`.

Comment: This works; do not use `inplace=True` on version 0.18.0, as it is not present.